# Why is "brake" often used in its plural form "brakes" even though a vehicle usually has only one?

Tags: word-usage

> He applied the brakes but failed to stop in time.

Why is "brake" often used in its plural form "brakes" even though a vehicle usually has only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/brake)

**brake**

> a device that slows or stops the movement of a vehicle

As stated by J.R, in your car you have a **brake pedal** and a **brake device per wheel** [multiple wheels, multiple devices, plural]; the action of pushing the pedal activate the **devices** and the car slows down.

Answer (score 2):

A vehicle usually only has one brake pedal – but it activates the two brakes (one on each wheel).

Answer (score 1):

I’m quite confident that my car has four brakes, one for each wheel.